# Show that the Wronskian of $x^{(1)},x^{(2)},x^{(3)}$ is identically zero or else never vanishes.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

My task is to prove that:

If $x^{(1)},x^{(2)},x^{(3)}$ are solutions of  $X'=A(t)X$ on some interval $I$, show that the Wronskian of $x^{(1)},x^{(2)},x^{(3)}$  is identically zero or else never vanishes.

After a long calculation I computed that the Wronskian is:

$e^{\int {(a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33})dt}}$. Where $a_{11},a_{22},a_{33}$ are entries from the matrix $A$. My question is:

How from $e^{\int {(a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33})dt}}$ the conclusion of my task follows?

I don't get it, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten a mulitplicative term, that is, the term $\det\left(x^{\left(1\right)}\left(t_{0}\right),x^{\left(2\right)}\left(t_{0}\right),x^{\left(3\right)}\left(t_{0}\right)\right) $ where $t_{0}$ is the initial time given in your initial conditions. I let you check your calculus, and find your answer thanks to this last term.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas but I dont get it, kindly enlighten me.

Comment: I got it now @Nicolas but how can that $t_0$ will help on showing what I want to show?

Comment: @JrAntalan the Wronskian is defined as the determinant of the solutions of the differential equation, which is also the determinant of the resolvant applied to the initial conditions...
If you do not see how to do, I can write a full answer.

Comment: Ok if you are fine with this term. Now the determinant of a family of vectors is non-zero if and only if these vectors are linearly independant...

Comment: Thanks again @Nicolas but how can i use it to show what i need to show?

Comment: Well, as you have observed, the exponential term never vanishs. Let us focus on the determinant term : if the initial conditions are linearly independant (as vectors in the vector space of the solutions of your linear differential equation), then for every time $t$, the Wronskian will not be zero. Instead, if the initial conditions are linearly dependant, then your Wronskian will be zero for all time $t$. The interesting thing here is that you can check the independance of your solutions by only checking the independance of the initial values.

Comment: Got it now, thanks @Nicolas